# How to absolute position, static positioned elements at the same position where they are?

Tags: jquery, css

A `#main` div is having a set of `.group` div containing 1 image each. All are positioned static.

```
<div id="main" class="mx-auto">
    <div class="group">
        <img src="" width="35">
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <img src="" width="35">
    </div>

    <div class="group">
        <img src="" width="35">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <img src="" width="35">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <img src="" width="35">
</div>
</div> <!-- main -->
```

Now, what I need is, when I hover over the `.group`, all other `.groups` should disappear and the hovered should stay at the same position.

The JavaScript I tried is here below.

```
$('.group').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.group').each(function() {
        $(this).css({
            'position'  : 'relative',
            'left'      : $(this).offset().left,
            'top'       : $(this).offset().top
        }); //$(this).css
    }); // $('.social-group').each
}); // $('.social-group').mouseenter
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't work. Can anyone point out what's wrong?

Comment: *when I hover over the .group, all other .groups should disappear* __ just hide all, keep hovered. why you used something like that?

Comment: 'when I hover over the .group, all other .groups should disappear and the hovered should stay at the same position'- will the hovered one will vary in size then ? Otherwise how can it stay in same position whereas other `.groups` `div`s have disappeared ?

Comment: I need it to be positioned so because, this isn't the whole action. After each img tag, there will be a span.description (hidden) having the description of each item. When I hover over one image, 1) all others disappear, afterthat 2) the hovered must move to the left most portion and 3) the description displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will save your day:

```
    $('.group').mouseenter(function(){
         $(this).siblings().css({'opacity':0});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
         $(this).siblings().css({'opacity':1});
    });
```

or you could animate the process like this:

```
    $('.group').mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).siblings().animate({'opacity':0},300);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).siblings().animate({'opacity':1},300);
    });
```